# Why was mysql-cluster removed from 12.04 and how can I install it?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, mysql, ndb

I was hoping to get a MySQL cluster up and running on 12.04, but for some reason, the package is marked deleted, and there is no alternative. I also trying searching for the ndb_mgm command, and there are no suggested packages.

Did it get yanked for a licensing reason? compatibility?

Is there any way to run a cluster on Precise short of building from sources? Does that even work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Did it get yanked for a licensing reason? compatibility?

It was deleted because it was not being actively maintained. See [Launchpad Bug #921152.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-cluster-7.0/+bug/921152)

> Is there any way to run a cluster on Precise short of building from sources? Does that even work?

Building from source should work because the package wasn't removed for FTBFS ("failure to build from source") -- it was removed for quality reasons.

There is an easier option: the pages saying "deleted" for the client and server also contain links to deb files for the packages, which are still available and can be installed via `dpkg`.

Before installing, use `dpkg -I package.deb | grep Depends` to find out the dependencies and then install them first using `apt-get`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up grabbing the binaries from Oracle, and they seem to be doing the trick.